# delete function never gets called in aspx.cs from .aspx

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

i have a problem. I am trying to delete something from a list but it never calls my delete function from the .aspx.cs

here is my javascript code:

```
function doTheDelete(doIDeleteExpenses) {
        if (selectedExpensesList.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //url: "/Tasks/ViewTasks.aspx/deleteTasksAndLinkedItems",
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Expenses/ViewExpenses.aspx/deleteSelectedExpense")%>',
                data: "{'DeleteExpenses' : " + "'" + doIDeleteExpenses + " '}",
                //dataaaaaa
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var ss = data.d;
                    if (ss.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
                            $.noty.consumeAlert({ layout: 'center', type: 'error', dismissQueue: true });
                            alert(ss[i]);

                        }
                    }
                    $("#viewTasksGrid").flexReload();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $.noty.consumeAlert({ layout: 'center', type: 'error', dismissQueue: true, modal: true });
                    alert('Error Deleting Expense');
                    if (window.console) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            showMessage('No expenses are selected.');
        }
    }

    function getSelectedExpenseIDs() {
        var selectedExpensesList = new Array;
        var i = 0;
        $('.expenseCheckBox:checked').each(function () {
            if ($(this)[0].id !== "checkAllExpenses") {
                selectedExpensesList[i] = $(this)[0].id.split('_')[1];
                ++i;
            }
        });
        return selectedExpensesList;
    }
```

and here is my method in the aspx.cs that never gets called:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] deleteSelectedExpense(bool DeleteExpenses, String[] ExpID)
{
    var rList = new List<string>();
    //var canDeleteTasks = false;
    //var canDeleteTrackers = false;
    var canDeleteExpenses = false;
    var investigatorID = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["InvestigatorID"];
    var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OSCIDConnectionString"].ToString());
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("p_Admin_Permissions_CanDeleteExpenses", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvestigatorID", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@InvestigatorID"].Value = investigatorID;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        canDeleteExpenses = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (SqlException sql)
    {
        if (!rList.Contains("Can not connect to the database. Please try again."))
            rList.Add("Can not connect to the database. Please try again.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (!rList.Contains("An Error Occured"))
            rList.Add("An Error Occured");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
    }

    if (canDeleteExpenses)
    {
        foreach (var expense in ExpID)
        {

            if (canDeleteExpenses && DeleteExpenses)
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString());
                cmd = new SqlCommand("p_DeleteExpenses", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TaskID", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmd.Parameters["@ExpID"].Value = int.Parse(expense);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmd.Parameters["@Message"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException sql)
                {
                    if (!rList.Contains("Error Connecting to the Database. Unable To Delete Expense(s)."))
                        rList.Add("Error Connecting to the Database. Unable To Delete Expense(s).");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (!rList.Contains("An Error Occured"))
                        rList.Add("An Error Occured");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (!canDeleteExpenses && DeleteExpenses)
            {
                rList.Add("You do not have permission to delete Expenses");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!rList.Contains("You do not have permission to delete the task(s)."))
                    rList.Add("You do not have permission to delete the task(s).");
            }
        }
    }
    //var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    //var re = serializer.Serialize(rList.ToArray());
    return rList.ToArray();
}
```

When I am in the browser console, it tells gives me an internal error(500). Well for obvious reasons.

Comment: The best way to diagnose problems of this sort is to install Fiddler and see what's really happening when you're making your call.  However, and FWIW, I don't think you need to wrap the `DeleteExpenses` label in your JSON in single quotes.  You also don't appear to be passing ExpID at all, so your method signatures won't match.

Comment: Also the amount of using `var` is truly atrocious and should be avoided for types that you should know or are aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are wrong. The `deleteSelectedExpense` method takes `bool` and `string[]` parameters, but you're only passing it the bool to flag wether to delete them.

EDIT: You're not passing your string array properly I'm guessing. When passing the array of string values, the json format should look like `expId : [ 1, 2, 3 ]`, which is why I'm using the `myArray.join` method and placing the brackets around the values.

```
var myArray = ['100', '200'];
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'WebForm1.aspx/testMethod',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: '{ del: true, expId : [' + myArray.join(",") + '] }',
         success: success,
         error: error
       });
function success(data) {
    $('#result').html(data.d);
}
function error(data) {
    $('#result').html(data.d);
}
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string testMethod(bool del, string[] expId)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    return rand.Next().ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you, i knew the parameters were off and that I needed to pass an extra paramter, I just wasn't quite sure.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am trying it.

Comment: Check my edit. Without seeing the issue I can't tell for sure, but I think you're probably not passing the array properly.

Comment: I am trying this right now :data: "{'DeleteExpenses' : ['" + doIDeleteExpenses + "']" + "'ExpID': ['" + selectedExpensesList.join(',') + "']}",

Comment: You only need brackets for passing the array - not for the boolean. Your json data value should be `data: "{ DeleteExpenses : " + doIDeleteExpenses + ", ExpID : [" + selectedExpensesList.join(',') + "]}"`